# Adding line break to textarea that is populated via .text()

Tags: jquery, textarea

I have a from that adds rows to a table. One of the cells is a `textarea`; I have added a script to add line breaks to this. However when it is added it actually writes the `<br>` text.

I think this is because I am calling the values using `.text()`.

I tried to replace the written `<br>` using `replaceWith()` but that didn't work either.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/XYkcx/11/).

Comment: @andy: The tag "jQuery" is already in the question tags, where it belongs; there is no need to duplicate it in an unindexed, inconsistent and redundant way in the title (indeed, if you do so, "jQuery" no longer shows up in the page titlebar, thus demonstrating that SO does _not_ expect you to write tags in titles). And the fiddle link is there. Perhaps your browser is not highlighting links in different colours from normal text?

Comment: @andy: No problem. If you can't recognise hyperlinks then perhaps the World Wide Web is not the place for you ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using .html() instead of .text().

Comment: Thanks, I feel really dumb, totally should have tried that, Cheers